# Java: Double not being calculated inside loop

Tags: java, loops, double, primitive-types

I am trying to move a projectile every 10 milliseconds using an animation loop in a separate class. The first two iterations of this loop print that gravity is equal to 0 when it should only be able to zero on the first loop since time = 0 at the start.

```
  public static void move()
    {
        System.out.println( "Time: " + time );
        System.out.println( "gravity: " + gravity );
        System.out.println( "g: " + g );
        dX = Slingshot.getPullX();
        dY = Slingshot.getPullY();
        gravity = 0.5 * g * time * time;
        newX = (double) Slingshot.getStart().x + time * c * dX;
        newY = (double) Slingshot.getStart().y + ( time * c * dY + gravity );
        time = time + 1;

        new Projectile( newX, newY, dX, dY );
        trail = new Ellipse( ( int ) newX + 5, ( int ) newY + 5 );
        trail.setColor( Color.RED );
        trail.setSize( 2, 2 );
        projectileTrail.add( trail );
    }
```

Here is the output after a few iterations of the loop:

```
Time: 0.0
gravity: 0.0
g: 2.0
Time: 1.0
gravity: 0.0
g: 2.0
Time: 2.0
gravity: 1.0
g: 2.0
Time: 3.0
gravity: 4.0
g: 2.0
Time: 4.0
gravity: 9.0
g: 2.0
Time: 5.0
gravity: 16.0
g: 2.0
```

Comment: Just as a tipp: This line  `new Projectile( newX, newY, dX, dY );` most likely does nothing. You create a projectile and since you don't do anything with it, it will only be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the results before you have calculated them, so the 2nd loop is showing what you calculated in the first.

Just move your `println`s to the end of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I was printing the values to try and find out what my error was so I was thinking that gravity being zero was causing my error. Looks like it is somewhere else!